# SQL Server 2008 log shipping keeps getting out of sync

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transaction-log, log-shipping

I have inherited a SQL Server 2008 live server with a hot swap-able backup server which has transaction logs shipped every 15 minutes from multiple production servers.  One of the production servers keeps getting out of sync, when I came it the last successful log restore on the backup was over a year ago... So clearly my predecessor wasn't watching this, I restored the database and ensured that the logs synced correctly at the next 15 minute interval.  However, every couple of days or so (it is random sometimes an hour sometimes 3 days) it gets back out of sync and I have to spend 10 minutes of my morning restoring the database.

Basically I am wondering what I need to be looking at to figure out why these keep getting out of sync? I ran a query I found on sqlauthority.com which shows me the trn's and their license numbers for the primary database and when I try to just restore the transaction logs on the backup database with the file which is supposed to be the next license to get it back in sync it says the license number is too recent, so I try the next file and it says is out of sync and can't be restored.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Upon digging into the job history further I found that my LS_Restore job was succeeding with errors, which were that the sql server agent service account didn't have access to the folder the trn files were stored which it was trying to restore the database from.

I researched what the original developer had setup as the sql server agent service account and then granted that user the necessary permissions, the logs are now restoring as needed.

I hope this information helps someone in the future!!